# How to set vagrant virtualbox video memory

Tags: virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have googled this and can't find what command allows me to allocate the video memory for when using vagrant and virtualbox. Can someone tell me what it is? This is what I have for my virtual box configuration so far:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.memory = 2048
  v.cpus = 1
  v.name = "Awesome Box"
end
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You'll need to use the following config:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "<vramsize in MB>"]
end
```

**How I found this?**
I looked at [VirtualBox docs](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) but haven't found anything about 'Video' or 'Memory' that seem related to video memory.
So I ran `VBoxManage showvminfo <vm name>` command and looked for the line with the amount of video memory I have set in Virtualbox GUI (12MB).

And then I saw:

```
VRAM size:       12MB
```

So now back to the documentation looking for 'vram' string.

Comment: Valid range according to my Virtual Box is anything between 0 to 256. More than so and he wouldn't start.

Comment: Customize uses vBoxManage. Here's all the possible options: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-cmd-overview